# How were the votes split on the Danish Folketing election the 26th of July 1881?

Tags: election, denmark

I'm researching Danish election results back from the first election in 1849.
However, I've been unable to find any information on the election the 26th of July 1881.
Wikipedia has an article for all Danish Folketing Elections but this one.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: The book "Elections in Europe: A data handbook" should have the information.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Folketing_election,_July_1881

Comment: Kind of, my problem is, that no party by the name of "Liberals" existed in 1881. I'm guessing they mean "Folketingets Venstre" but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A simple switch to the Danish language](http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folketingsvalget_26._juli_1881) in Wikipedia gives the answer:

```
Parti                    Mandater   +/–
Folketingets Venstre        75      +6
Højre                       27      –6
```

Comment: Hmm. Now I feel... strange. @Locercus, could you just borrow that book from a library to check the data? The state library in Aarhus seems to [have it](http://old.bibliotek.dk/linkme.php?ref=worldcat&ccl=wcx%3D762066001) even for international users. Otherwise, the same data might be also in [this book](http://old.bibliotek.dk/linkme.php?ref=worldcat&ccl=wcx%3D60982915), also available for borrowing.

Comment: I have borrowed the first one, however they only have it in the capital for some reason. I'll have to wait for it to arrive.

Comment: I am highly amused at citing the questioner's wikipedia edit as the answer to the question.  Nothing wrong with it, just an amusing turn of events.  --- That being said, where did you get the data for your edit from, @Locercus?  Is that source sufficient, or were you asking here in order to confirm the edit you made there?

Comment: I'm asking here to confirm my edit.